# Spring Data Neo4j trows NotInTransactionException on access of already retrieved object

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I just updated a project from SDN2 to SDN3 in a Spring environment and went through the necessary changes like forcing legacy simple indexing and Indexed TypeRepresentationStrategy.

Context boots up just fine but given the following code...

```
@RequestMapping({"/customer/browse"})
public String customerBrowse(final ModelMap model) {
    populateBaseModel(model);
    Result<Customer> result = this.customerService.findAll();
    for(Customer c : result) {
        LOG.info("Customer: {}", c.getName());
    }
    model.addAttribute("allCustomer", result);
    return "pages/browse";
}
```

...the findAll() repository call runs perfectly while the mere access to the retrieved Customer objects `for(Customer c : result)` triggers a NotInTransactionException (see below). The Customer class has several legacy index annotation but no outgoing references. To me its unclear on why a simple access to successful retrieved objects would run into a NotInTransactionException. I'm running SDN in simple mode and would assume that the foreach is running on detached Customer objects.

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.assertInTransaction(LuceneIndex.java:631)
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.access$000(LuceneIndex.java:58)
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex$1.hasNext(LuceneIndex.java:359)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)
at com.myapp.controller.CustomerController.customerBrowse(CustomerController.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1448)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter.doFilter(DandelionFilter.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:198)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:176)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.__doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:488)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:932)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:994)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Trace output before the exception:

```
| org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod            | Invoking [CustomerController.customerBrowse] method with arguments [{}] 
| o.s.d.r.c.s.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource | Adding transactional method 'findAll' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; '' 
| o.s.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory    | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'neo4jTransactionManager' 
| o.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager | Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.NodeGraphRepositoryImpl.findAll]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; '' 
| o.s.t.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager         | Initializing transaction synchronization 
| o.s.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor      | Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.NodeGraphRepositoryImpl.findAll] 
| o.s.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor      | Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.NodeGraphRepositoryImpl.findAll] 
| o.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager | Triggering beforeCommit synchronization 
| o.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager | Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization 
| o.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager | Initiating transaction commit 
| o.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager | Triggering afterCommit synchronization 
| o.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager | Triggering afterCompletion synchronization 
| o.s.t.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager         | Clearing transaction synchronization
```

The transaction scope is handled by the service layer underneath:

```
  @Service
  @Transactional
  public class CustomerService implements AssetService, ApplicationContextAware {

      @Autowired
      private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

          ...

          public Result<Customer> findAll() {
            return this.customerRepository.findAll();
          }

          ...
  }
```

The SDN manual talks about auto transactions are catered for some of its methods. As it seems from the log this worked fine with the findAll() call but this still leaves open on why the access of the retrieved objects fail.

Would really appreciate if anyone can point me to the right direction of troubleshooting here.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but this post may be relevant reading.  This is a strange problem; something similar has cropped up before, and it didn't have an identified solution.  The trick is finding a case that can really be duplicated well I think.   https://groups.google.com/d/topic/neo4j/w1L_21z0z04/discussion

Comment: Seems like you cannot work with a SDN provided Result or Iterator in a non-transactional scope. If I let queries return Collection/List etc. then things work in non-transactional scope. Maybe I missed this in the docs.

However this renders the default findAll() useless if you just want to pass their result up to the view template layer (as this is out of transaction scope for sure). You would need to always make sure that you use SDN result types up to the service layer only...

Comment: Disclaimer: Don't know SDN at detailed level.

One of the changes from Neo4j 1.9 -> 2.x was the need for mandatory transactions on reads. Not 100% sure what `findAll` does under the hoods but I think the iteration reads something and therefore needs a transactional context which your controller does not seem to have.

Wouldn't it make sense to refactor the iteration into a transactional service method that returns a `List<Customer>`?

Comment: As far as it looks it's not the findAll() that fails but the access on the returned Result/Iterator type afterwards.

Comment: The iterator is lazy, so it doesn't read the nodes-properties up until it is used. So you would have to convert it into a collection in transactional scope. We should probably change that into an eager collection. Can you raise a JIRA issue? Thanks

Comment: Also can you show your `CustomerService`?

Comment: I've updated the original post with CustomerService details. I'll open a corresponding JIRA issue. Thanks you, Michael.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It seems that the myRepository has its own transaction and as soon as I get the result i change it to a list and get NotIntransactionError or NullpointerException ...

Comment: The issue mentioned above is referenced here:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-531

Answer (score 2):

I got the same exact Exception when iterating through a Result, and after reading several comments here and there I sorted it out this way:

```
@Repository
public class OrderDAO implements DaoOperations<Order> {

@Autowired
private Neo4jOperations neo4j;
@Autowired
private GraphDatabase gd;

public List<Order> findAll() {

    List<Order> list = new ArrayList<Order>();

    try (Transaction tx = gd.beginTx()) { 
        Result<Order>res = neo4j.findAll(Order.class);
        list =IteratorUtil.asList(res);
    } 

    return list;
  }
}
```

Note that the method neo4j.findAll() originally returns a Result, I converted this into a List **within a transaction** and that solved the problem, now I can iterate through the List without throwing any exceptions in my Service/Controller. Hope this helps.